# Resettable integrator resetting to the negative rail not ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, jfet, integrator, sample-and-hold

I've recently built a resettable integrator board which uses a low-drift JFET [op-amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa140.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1703055768263&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fopa140) and a [sample and hold](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf398-n.pdf) chip. The sample and hold amplifier datasheet showed a resettable integrator configuration which is what I used to design my PCB, although with a different op-amp.
I simulated the circuit in Spice and it worked as advertised with my chosen op-amp. Once assembled the circuit integrated as expected but when reset, it would reset to the -12 V rail and not ground.
I suspected grounding the negative rail of the sample and hold amplifier might fix the problem and to some extent it did. Once grounded the integrator would integrate up and down and would reset towards ground but had a ~2 V offset when reset and instead of integrating up/down to +-12 V the integrator would stop at +8 V and -2 V.
Any ideas on what might be wrong or what could be done? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How do you use this circuit?

Comment: Currently, just applying a voltage between the two input terminals via a power supply and periodically pulsing the reset lines with a 5 V signal. The integration and reset work fine aside from the signal resets to -12 V and not 0 V.

Comment: When I read chapter 9.1.2 of the datasheet, my understanding is, that the offset adjust pin needs a voltage close to V+ and connecting this to GND is not intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of debugging it turns out it was the offset pin. Apply voltage to the offset pin offered no change to the circuits function, I applied voltage up to the positive rail with no difference. Leaving the offset pin floating solved the problem and now the integrator resets to 0V every time with no hassle. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @Jens ...

See figure 37, page 24 ... (pin 2 or 14 wired to quasi 15 V ...).

Pin 2 or 14 is not "grounded" but quasi at +15 V.

[image]